# How to make activity only run once after receiving multiple outputs with SC Orchestrator?

Tags: orchestration, system-center

I'm using orchestrator to check if a collection of servers need to be rebooted. Here is my runbook:
[image]

The first activity will return multiple outputs with the ips of each server that I want to verify if they have a reboot pending. The next activity will invoke another runbook that only verifies if the server needs to be rebooted and that information will be added to a text file. The last activity will format some data.

(I need to check this information on two servers)

Right now the Get Hosts Name/IP runs once, the Reboot Pending activity runs twice (once for each server), and the last activity also runs twice.
I wanted to make the last activity only to run once, but I right now, no matter what I do it runs always twice.

I already tried to configure the Run Behavior Tab and Flattened the returned data. I did this in the Reboot Pending activity and the last activity. However, nothing seems to be working.

How can I make the last activity only run once after the activity before runs twice?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Junction Activity and configured the Return data from